# Java keywords not changing color in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

I just launched Eclipse and I am brand new to it.  None of my Java code is changing color for some reason code highlighting is off.  Why is this?  Thanks

Note that I am using the latest version of Eclipse.

**EDIT**: Ok, code highlighting is finally on after I restarted eclipse.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: usually that doesn't happen if you save the file with .java extension.

Comment: Are you sure that you downloaded an Eclipse with Java Development Tools? There are bundles without it. When you select New -> Project from the menu, can you create a "Java Project"?

Answer (score 4):

Make certain that your file is indeed a Java file, i.e. has the `.java` extension. Also, you can check ***Eclipse -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Syntax Coloring***. In the *Element* box, search for *Keywords*.

Comment: it is a java file...and it seems like all the highlighting is turned off..also seems like i have to go in manually and turn on each individual element...

Comment: that's very strange, where did you download Eclipse from?

Answer (score 2):

right click the file and make sure open with Java editor is checked and not for example the Text editor

Comment: Does not answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem. the fix for me was actually changing the "theme" in personal settings on my desktop to the default setting. I had it on the "High Contrast" theme and it was changing all the text in eclipse to black. When I looked at my preferences (as recommended above) I noticed colors were assigned to the text, but they were all black. Once I restored the default theme all the text coloring worked in eclipse. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can check the "Outline" panel. If there is a warning link there mentioning "Scalability". You can go on Preferences > Editor > Scalability and "Disabled" all the checkboxes under "Scalability mode settings" and click "Apply". It worked for me after that. It seemed like it was disabled because I was opening a big file.